# Using string variables

Tags: c#, variables

Some part of my program. i want to add "TiklananDugme" and "SeciliNesne" variables in to the  TextBox1.

I want to show "TiklananDugme" and "SeciliNesne" variables values in the text box. 
When i selected (after clicking ImageButton1) any row from GridView4. TextBox1 shows only "11"

What is wrong here?

There isn'n any other using place these variables.(Because of i didn't put another part of my code)

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

namespace OTS_WF.Moduller.Ogretmen
{
    public partial class Odevler : Page
    {
        string VTYolu = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataBaglantisi1_Access"].ToString();
        string MevcutBolum = "Odevler";
        string TiklananDugme;
        string SeciliNesne;
        OleDbConnection con;
        OleDbCommand cmd;
        OleDbDataReader dr;
        int MaxId = 0;
        int k = 0; //Kayıt id için 
        string SonucDers;
        string SonucOkul;
        string SonucSinif;
        string SonucTarih;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //there is codes but i erase to easy understanding;
        }
    }

    protected void GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "11";

        if (SeciliNesne == "TextBox1")
        {
            TextBox1.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
        }
        if (SeciliNesne == "TextBox2") 
        {
            TextBox2.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView4.Rows)
            {
                TextBox innerTextBox = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox4x");
                innerTextBox.Text = TextBox2.Text;
            }
            TextBox2.Focus();
        }
        if (SeciliNesne == "TextBox3")
        {
            TextBox3.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
            TextBox3.Focus();
        }
        TextBox1.Text+= TiklananDugme + SeciliNesne;
    }

    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView2.Visible = !GridView2.Visible;
        Label12.Visible = !Label12.Visible;
        TiklananDugme = "OdevSonuc";
        SeciliNesne = "TextBox3";
        OncekiYazilanlarParametre();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Erdnic , does answer posted below solves your problem ? if not can you please specify the error/unexpected beahvior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to understand this i advice you to understand asp.net [page life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

***Background***

When you click  `ImageButton1` you 'postback' your webpage that is :  a request is sent by browser to the server and the page is loaded from scratch and after that your `ImageButton1_Click` function gets executed.

You are assigning `SeciliNesne = "TextBox3";` on `ImageButton1_Click` event. How this actually works is your page is initialized and `SeciliNesne` variable is declared , then your `ImageButton1_Click` event is called and `SeciliNesne` is set to `"TextBox3"`

Now when `GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged` is called this cycle is repeated i.e.your page is initialized and `SeciliNesne` variable is declared , then your `GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged` event is called you check if `SeciliNesne` is equal to `"TextBox3"`

Please note that at this point `SeciliNesne` is not set to `"TextBox3"` because every time page loads it gets declared again.

In `GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged` what happens is :

```
TextBox1.Text = "11"; // you set the value of textbox

if (SeciliNesne == "TextBox1")// always false
{
    '''''''''''''''
    ''''''''''''''

}
if (SeciliNesne == "TextBox2") // always false
{
   ''''''''''''''
   ''''''''''''' 

}
if (SeciliNesne == "TextBox3") // always false
{
    '''''''''''''''
    '''''''''''''''
}
```

At this point of time the changes you made on table on client side are NOT available and hence you DO NOT find `SeciliNesne` value which was set during previous click event. You will only find what's been declared on aspx page.

**Solution**

There are a number of ways to do this , one of them is to use [`ViewState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx)

*I am not claiming this is the best way to do it, but should be able to solve your specific problem*

in your `ImageButton1_Click` event do this :

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
 ''''''''''''''
 '''''''''''''
 ViewState["yourKeyHere"] = "TextBox3";
}
```

Then in your `GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged` event

```
TextBox1.Text = "11"; // you set the value of textbox

if (ViewState["yourKeyHere"]  == "TextBox1")
{
    '''''''''''''''
    ''''''''''''''
}
if (ViewState["yourKeyHere"] == "TextBox2") 
{
   ''''''''''''''
   ''''''''''''' 

}
if (ViewState["yourKeyHere"]  == "TextBox3") 
{
    '''''''''''''''
    '''''''''''''''
}
```